Manage multiple resolution screen
I have a laptop with Ubuntu 24. The laptop screen has a resolution of 2560x1600 (16:10). I also use a second monitor with a resolution of 3440x1440 (21:9). Sometimes I use only the laptop without the second monitor.
My problem is as follows: the applications on the laptop screen have a font that is too small, and I can't see anything (Chromium, IDE, terminal, etc.), so I changed the settings to increase the font size. However, when I use the external monitor and open these applications on it, the font is huge. Do you know how I can manage this?
Also, how can I make it so that when the second monitor is connected, the search and everything else is displayed on it, but if it's not connected, it shows on the laptop screen (same for the app switcher with alt-tab)? I tried setting the second monitor as the "Primary display", but when I do that and disconnect the second monitor, nothing displays correctly. It seems that the computer doesn't detect when I disconnect the second monitor because the applications open on the external screen do not display anymore when I disconnect it. But I don't understand how to make it work.
